# Why using react state is not advisable(not considered best practice) when using redux in application

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-form

```
class Wrap extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      index: 0,
      selectedIndex: 0
    };
  }
  getSelectedIndex(index){
    this.setState({selectedIndex: index});
  }

  switch(index) {
    case 0:
    <Apple selectedIndex={this.getSelectedIndex.bind(this)}/>;
    case 1:
    <Orange selectedIndex={this.state.selectedIndex}/>;
    case 2:
    <Pumpkin selectedIndex={this.state.selectedIndex}/>;
  }    
}
```

Here using selectedIndex in react state is not advised. It should be moved to redux store. Why is not best practice, when it is only required within the parent-child components.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official docs](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizingstate#organizing-state), using local state is fine, or you can put it all into the redux store. Its up to you and your project's needs.

Key things to consider here:

> Some common rules of thumb for determining what kind of data should be
>   put into Redux:
>
> - Do other parts of the application care about this data?
> - Do you need to be able to create further derived data based on this
>     original data?
> - Is the same data being used to drive multiple components?
> - Is there value to you in being able to restore this state to a given
>     point in time (ie, time travel debugging)?
> - Do you want to cache the data (ie, use what's in state if it's already
>     there instead of re-requesting it)?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have the application state in one place but often times it's really hard to avoid having local state in some components.